# Send response to client after Promise resolves - Adonis, Node.js

Tags: node.js, promise

I have some promise

```
getSomeInfo(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      /* ...some code... */

      someObject.getData((err, info) => {
        if (info) {
          resolve(info)
        }
        else {
          reject("Error")
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

I use this promise and want to send response to client from Controller (AdonisJS):

```
async create ({ request, response }) {
        this.getSomeInfo(data).then(info => {
              console.log(info) // It's work, i get the data from promise

              response.status(201).json({ // but this is not work
                code: 201,
                message: "Data received!",
                data: info
              })
            })
}
```

Why response is not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this.

```
async create ({ request, response }) {
    const info = await this.getSomeInfo(data)
    console.log(info)

    response.status(201).json({
        code: 201,
        message: "Data received!",
        data: info
    })
}
```

Comment: To catch errors I need to use try-catch for `await this.getSomeInfo(data)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your `console.log(info)` inside of `create()` works and shows the data you want, but the `response.status(201).json(...)` does not send a response, then I can see the following possibilities:

1. You've already sent a response to this request (and thus cannot send another one)
2. The `.json()` method is having trouble converting `info` to JSON (perhaps because of circular references) and throwing an exception.
3. You aren't passing the arguments `request` and `response` properly and thus `response` isn't what it is supposed to be.

You can test for the second case like this:

```
create ({ request, response }) {
    this.getSomeInfo(data).then(info => {
        console.log(info) // It's work, i get the data from promise

        response.status(201).json({ // but this is not work
            code: 201,
            message: "Data received!",
            data: info
        });
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log("Error in create()", e);
        response.sendStatus(500);
    });
}
```

Also, there is no reason for this method to be declared `async` as you don't show that you're using `await` or any of the features of an `async` function.

---

In the comments, you say that this function is called directly by a router (I assume an Express router).  If that's the case, then the function arguments are not declared properly as they come as two separate arguments, not as properties of an object.  Change the function declaration to this:

```
create (request, response) { ... }
```

Comment: 1. I dont send any more response. Only one.

Comment: 3. It seems to be all right. As in dev docs. In other controller method "create" works successfully with passed object `{request, response}`

Comment: @pHabb - Please show the code you are calling `create()` with.  My guess is that you aren't called the `create()` function properly.

Comment: It is calling by router (adonis.js)

Comment: @pHabb - Then it's declared wrong.  It should be `async create(req, res) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

When marking a function as `async` the function must return a `Promise`, this can be done explicitly.

```
async create({ request, response }) {
    return this.getSomeInfo(data).then(info => {
        console.log(info) // It's work, i get the data from promise

        response.status(201).json({ // but this is not work
            code: 201,
            message: "Data received!",
            data: info
        })
    })
}
```

Or implicitly using the `await` keyword.

```
async create({ request, response }) {
    const info = await this.getSomeInfo(data)
    console.log(info) // It's work, i get the data from promise

    response.status(201).json({ // but this is not work
        code: 201,
        message: "Data received!",
        data: info
    })
}
```